# stop shifting of other divs when hover in a responsive UI

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-experience

[In this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6nUfcqyFIDreFlJmzdDg?p=preview), the id `#chat-msgs` is getting shifted downwards when the user hover over **All Conversations**  (when browser width is < 767px).
I tried implementing `position: absolute` but its not working as expected.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
#user-list {
    display: none;
}
#chat-msgs {
  position:absolute;
}

#dropdownMenu2:hover + #user-list, #user-list:hover{  
  display: block;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you thought position absolute would do there, but position absolute works best when it's wrapped in something that has position relative.  Position absolute takes the element out of the regular flow, if it's contained in something that's position: relative, that element will 'catch' it in a sense and it won't go beyond the bounds of that element unless you specifically tell it to with css.

What you should be taking out of the flow is #user-list.  If you take it out of the flow, it won't push other elements around.

Try:

```
.dropdown{ position: relative; }

#dropdownMenu2:hover + #user-list, #user-list:hover{
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
   background: #fff;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On your body tag you need to hide the overflow as you seem to have handled the overflow elsewhere in your code:

body { overflow:hidden; }

Comment: I tried putting `body {overflow:hidden;}` in the css file but I cant see any effect. Can you please share a plnkr :(